# How to join many columns of data in array?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I have large number of columns of data. How to put in single matrix?

For example, with test data of 1 x 3 matrixs

```
test[1] = {1, 1, 1}
test[2] = {2, 2, 2}
test[3] = {3, 3, 3}
test[4] = {4, 4, 4}
```

I use

```
Array[test, 4, 1, Join]
```

and get 1 x 12 matrix

```
{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4}
```

I want to get 4 x 3 matrix

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
```

Comment: Don't you already have a 4 x 3 matrix or let's say 2-dimensional array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try creating an `Array` and then Transposing:

```
In[14]:= Transpose @ Array[test, 4]

Out[14]= {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
num = 4;
test[#] & /@ Range[num] // Transpose
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}

Comment: `test /@ Range...` will do too.

Answer (score 5):

```
Array[test, 4, 1, Transpose[{##}] &]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}

also

```
Array[test, 4, 1, Flatten[{##}, {2}] &]
Array[test, 4, 1, Thread[{##}] &]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility:

```
Array[List /@ test[#] &, 4, 1, Join[##, 2] &]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps in creating the array you're asking about.

```
Var matrix = new int [4, 3];   
     //this creates an array (of arrays) with 4 rows, 3 columns in each row

IF THE VALUES ARE KNOWN (AS IN YOUR CASE) = 
Var matrix = new int [4, 3];
{
    {1, 1, 1}
    {2, 2, 2}
    {3, 3, 3}
    {4, 4, 4}
}
```